I want to divide different index
On below dataframe, I want to divide "Inventory" value by "OUT" value with +1 index and output to DOH columns.
For example, my expected output DOH columns on index 1 are the "OUT" value on index 1(50) by "Inventory" value on index 0 ( 20)



index
Month
IN
OUT
Inventory
DOH




0
Jan
120
100
20
0.2


1
Feb
80
50
50
1.0


2
Mar
60
60
50
0.8333333333333334


3
Apr
80
70
60
0.8571428571428571


4
May
100
120
40
0.3333333333333333



My first try is below:
df['DOH']=df['Inventory'].div (df['OUT '])

But in this case, calculation is applied between same index ( above dataframe)
Then I tried below. But did not work out.
df['DOH']=df['Inventory'].div (df.iloc['OUT '+1:])

Please advice on how I can divide between different index.

You can use df['Inventory'] / df['OUT'].shift(-1):
import pandas as pd

D = {
    'Month': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
    'IN': [120, 80, 60, 80, 100],
    'OUT': [100, 50, 60, 70, 120],
    'Inventory': [20, 50, 50, 60, 40],
    'DOH': [0.2, 1.0, 0.8333333333333334, 0.8571428571428571, 0.3333333333]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(D)
df['DOH'] = df['Inventory'] / df['OUT'].shift(-1)
print(df)


Prints
  Month   IN  OUT  Inventory       DOH
0   Jan  120  100         20  0.400000
1   Feb   80   50         50  0.833333
2   Mar   60   60         50  0.714286
3   Apr   80   70         60  0.500000
4   May  100  120         40       NaN


